# Retrieving a visitor's browser/version and storing it in the database

Tags: php, mysql, user-agent

I have a mysql set up and it is full working however there is one thing more I would like to do. Is there a way that when a user enters their username and password and clicks login in it will store their browser and browser version in in a new column in mysql?

Comment: @BradChristie what do you mean

Comment: I think Brad means what are the users logging in to? Is it a php website?

Comment: if is PHP, then you can get client agent from $_SERVER, like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm assuming the server-side technology is [php](/questions/tagged/php) since you're mentioning [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). If that's incorrect, let me know and I'll correct the following.*

```
<?php
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

  $db = new PDO(...);
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
  if (($result = $query->execute(array($username, MD5($password)))) !== false){
    // login user
    $log = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log (username, agent) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $log->execute(array($username, $agent));
  }
```

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to get their browser (and parse the value to determine the actual agent (e.g. IE, Firefox, Opera, etc.)) then save that information back to the database.

---

### Update

First, you need to add a new column to the `user` table to allow for an additional piece of information (the browser):

```
ALTER TABLE   user
ADD COLUMN    useragent VARCHAR(100);
```

This will need to be performed directly on the database, so however you added the `user` table intially, you'll need to execute the above code (phpMyAdmin I'm guessing?)

Next you need to modify your `UPDATE` call to also include the useragent:

```
$sql = "UPDATE  user
        SET     logindate = NOW(),
                useragent = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) . "'
        WHERE   username = '" . $input_username . "'";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Error in SQL: ' . mysql_error());
```

And that should be all there is to it.

Comment: could i do it like this:        $sql = "UPDATE test SET $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']) . "'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());

but what would my column called be in mysql db?

Comment: @jing: It's recommending you use PDO, but you can use `mysql_query` as well, just make sure to `mysql_escape_string` the user agent as this is something that can be modified by the user (spoofing headers). You also would need a column added tot he database to accept this new piece of information (most likely a `VARCHAR` data type).

Comment: Thanks, if it was my above example what would my column need to be called?

Comment: @jing: that's up to you and your database. However, you can use `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN useragent VARCHAR(100)` and add a column to the end of the table you wish to modify. (then the column would be named `useragent`)

Comment: ok but how would my could above know to put it in useragent if thats what i called it?

Comment: `UPDATE users SET useragent= $useragent WHERE username = $username AND password = $password` (or something similar).

Comment: Still having issues,I have edited the post above and put my php code in. thanks

Comment: It works but only for the first time after that no-one can log in?

Comment: @jing: What problem(s) are occurring, and what is causing the user to not be able to login? (Can't find a user/pass match in database, UPDATE call applies to all accounts, etc.)?

Comment: when username and password is entered it just goes back into login page